# Help editing assembly with IDA

Tags: ida, binary

I have the line:

```
mov [esp+var], ebp
```

and want to change it to:

```
mov [esp+var], ebp+20
```

To my understanding, Edit>Patch Program>Change Byte, is what should be used.. but I know very little on to what to change the hex values to to make the above change. 
Is there anywhere I can read up or does someone have a simple explanation? It seems like something that would be relatively simple to do if known how.

Comment: While some answers in Jason's link apply to this question as well, i wouldn't consider it a duplicate, because that questions generally ask for tools, and this question asks about how to use IDA.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, thanks, I meant to direct user1091684 to yrp's answer on the "duplicate" thread. Unfortunately, there's no way to say, "this has already been answered here", but only "this has already been asked here" which as you pointed out is not quite correct :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are able to use **mov** instruction from **mem arg** to **mem arg**, see:

[x86 MOV Instruction Set Reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html)

I guess should save ebp+20 to reg, then load it to mem via mov.